# Was Lando referring to this event on Cloud City?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Han piloted the Millennium Falcon to Cloud City. Upon arrival at the gas-mining colony Han's party was welcomed by menacing Lando Calrissian and his motley team. Lando greeted Han with offensive tone in his voice and made Han uneasy.

> **Lando:** Why, you slimy, double-crossing, no-good swindler!  You've got
>   a lot of guts coming here, after what you pulled.

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we on the other hand saw how

> Han and Chewbacca entered a Sabacc game room on a tropical world.
>  First, Han moved threateningly towards Lando, but then friendly
>  embraced him – and swiped a spare card out of his sleeve. This move
>  helped Han to win the card game and gain the Falcon.

Was this the event Lando was referring to on one of the landing platforms of Cloud City over 10 years later? Storywise it would make sense. I especially like how Lando did

> the same diversion move to fool his
>  friend as Han did on him on the jungle world.

But then, there are issues that I find conflicting in this. Lando called Han "double-crossing swindler", though he actually prevented *him* from cheating in the game. I've also always thought Han won the Falcon in a dice game, with the ones that have been shown in a number of movies lately. Additionally, in his opening line, Lando underlined Han having the nerve to "come here", to Cloud City.

So, did Han and Lando have another meeting(s) after the event in the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, in which they finally broke their companionship apart, or was Lando referring to

> the Sabacc rematch particularly?

Comment: future works most likely considering that the stars have a three film contract

Comment: It’s probably meant to be the same event, but there wasn’t really anything in *Solo* that involved Han “double-crossing” Lando. Lazy writing or a reference to something else? You make the call!

Comment: not likely - for one thing, in Empire, it seems clear that Lando is making a joke. Han gives a confused look and points to himself like "me? What are you talking about" - Lando throws a fake punch and then starts laughing and hugging him. Later, Han says Lando lost the ship to him [Han] 'fair and square' and Lando does not argue this point. So, maybe Han and Lando never met again after the events of Solo and the scene in Empire does refer [retconned] to it, or it will refer to some later event [upcoming Solo films], or its just a joke by Lando

Comment: @NKCampbell - In the Solo novels, it was a bit of a swindle on Solo's part due to a misstatement by Lando. As part of a sabaac game, Lando offers the choice of "Any ship on my lot" as part of the bet, and the Falcon (Lando's personal ship at the time) happened to be on the lot at the time of the wager.

Comment: Come on.  Put on your Doylist hat.  Obviously the writers in 1982 didn't know what was going to be on film in 2018.  But you don't have to strain your Watsonian credulity at all to see that the final meeting in Solo doesn't really match Lando's quote, but that there is lots more room timewise for them to have had other encounters after that.

Comment: Irritatingly, the Solo movie ends with Han and Lando on very bad terms, with Han outright cheating to win the Falcon (which has Lando's droid in it now), and Lando knowing exactly what he did.  But given their relationship in ESB, the only reasonable option is that they've had a developed friendship over the years that we DON'T SEE ON SCREEN.  It's annoying, but it's the best we've got for canon right now.

Answer (score 9):

Not likely. If the card game on the tropical planet was the last interaction between Han and Lando prior to the visit to Cloud City, I hardly think that Han would have felt comfortable enough seeking refuge with Lando, as it was obvious that they neither liked nor trusted one another. I think it is implied that Han and Lando have crossed paths many times throughout the years, and apparently gained enough of a friendship that Lando and Han actually embrace each other when they meet again in Empire Strikes Back.

It could be that greeting each other with accusations has become a friendly joke between them, since we see a similar interaction before the card game at the end of Solo. Perhaps they carried this tradition on throughout the years. This is supported by Han's reaction to the attack, which is confusion rather than his normal style of trying to talk his way out of it. If Han had actually known what Lando was talking about, he would have 1) not reacted the way he did, and 2)not come to Cloud City in the first place.

Alternatively, if this is not the case, perhaps Lando is trying to scare Han into leaving Cloud City before he falls into Vader's trap. Remember that Lando does not actually want to betray Han, he would probably have attempted to warn Han in some way.

Finally, if neither of these is true, and some event did occur, it was definitely not the card game for the Falcon. That card game would have happened ~10 years prior to the interaction on Cloud City, and I doubt that was the most recent quarrel Lando and Han have had. Perhaps we will get more insight into what actually happened in a future movie. Remember, the actors have all agreed to at least 2 more films!

TLDR: No. There's too much evidence to support other options.